# Can we view H2-console when using spring beans Configuration?

Tags: spring, h2, spring-bean

I have to persist the following class

```
public class Hotel {
    @Id
    private String hotelName;
    private String RoomType;
    private String status;
    private int Price;
    private int gst;
```

and I need to open the H2-console to check If the table is created properly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring Servlet.xml I would use the following bean property:

```
<bean id="h2Server"class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer"init-method="start"destroy-method="stop">
<constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8086"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a property you set to true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Try that, should work

Comment: If I use Xml-mapping how can I do that??